# diskpart multiple primary partition keys

Tags: linux, boot, usb-flash-drive, diskpart, usb-boot

[image: DISKPART Screen Capture]

I am trying to set up partitions on my USB drive, 1x as a boot partition, 1x as operating system data, 1x as shared with windows files. I am trying to assign the shared with windows partiton a drive latter using `diskpart`, however, I can not select the partition I need. Using `list part`, the three partitions are listed, but I can not select the 8b partition, because it, along with another partition, share a partition id of `0`. How can I assign a drive letter to the 8gb partition of this drive?

Comment: Although it really sounds as an error to have two identical partition numbers, may I ask, why you don't use the graphical partitioner _aka_ "Disk Management Console"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact setup in which I need is taking much more time and effort then I thought... However, this part of the problem, I have managed to solve.

As *pmbiesiada* mentioned, Windows does not like more then two partitions on a USB drive... Simple solution, make the windows visible partition first. The other 2 are an extended format and bootable anyway. This is giving me more or less the setup I desire, in that only the 8gb is visible to the user in windows, and my boot and casper drives are hidden.

I appreciate the provided input.
Thanks
~Matt

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to clean the USB drive using diskpart and then set the partitions once again, to achieve what you want. This is not common, that two partitions are set as #0. Also, in Windows, there is rule, that the USB sticks (not hard disk drives connected via USB) can have only one partition (normally).